# POST api call parameters android studio

Tags: android, api, kotlin

[PARAMETERS to be passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QU56.png)

```
   // this is the relevant method
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String>? {
            val params: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            params["documents"] = arrayListOf<String>().toString()
            return params
        }
    }
```

I want to pass the image parameters in my POST API call but I am unable to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You need send the data in Multipart when the POST method involves the file. Check  [This](https://medium.com/@Tarek360/upload-file-via-multipart-post-method-in-kotlin-d43d3f025670)

If you want to use Retofit check  [This](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/making-multipart-requests-in-android-with-retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make multipart request to the server. Below example may help you.

ApiInterface.java

```
@Multipart
@POST("addExpertImage")
Call<ImageUploadResponse> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, 
@Part("user_email") RequestBody userEmail, @Part("server_id") RequestBody 
serverId, @Part("folder_name") RequestBody folderName);
```

Network call

```
final File file = new File(imageData.getFilePath());

                // create RequestBody instance from file
                final RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

                // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
                MultipartBody.Part body =
                        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);
                RequestBody serverId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), String.valueOf((Integer) imageData.getServerId()));
                RequestBody userEmail = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), (String) PrefSettings.getInstance(context).get(Constants.USER_EMAIL));
                RequestBody folderName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), imageData.getFolderName());

                Call<ImageUploadResponse> resultCall = ApiClient.getInstance().create(ApiInterface.class).uploadImage(body, userEmail, serverId, folderName);
```

Comment: ok I will try to implement this